# Which PixelFormat in WritableBitmap for uncompressed image data?

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, dng, writablebitmap

I'm writing an image viewer application showing pure content of digital images stored in CR2, CR3, ARW, TIFF, JPG and DNG format. To show the image content, I use the `WritableBitmap`. The image data is extracted from the image file, stored in a buffer and written to the `WritableBitmap` using the `WritePixels` method. Most of these digital image formats use internally 3 x 8 or 3 x 16 bits to store the pixel data (uncompressed or as JPG). For these images, I use the `PixelFormats.Rgb24`or `PixelFormats.Rgb48`.

Some DNG images have the following tags:

- Compression: Uncompressed
- SamplesPerPixel: 1
- BitsPerSample: 16

and I'm not able to find the proper `PixelFormats` value. "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception is raised, and I have no idea what is wrong here.

Does someone have an idea or some detailed explanation about `WritableBitmap` usage ?

[UPDATE]
To better explain the problem here a short code snapshot:

```
With dngItemRD
  If .SourceIFD IsNot Nothing AndAlso .MainImageBuffer IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim cpr As CompressionValues = .SourceIFD.GetEntryValueIFD(TagIDsTIFF.Compression)
    If cpr = CompressionValues.Jpeg_old OrElse cpr = CompressionValues.JPEG Then
      Me.MainImage = GetJpgBitmapImage(.MainImageBuffer)
    ElseIf cpr = CompressionValues.Uncompressed Then
      Dim iWidth As Integer = .SourceIFD.GetEntryValueIFD(TagIDsTIFF.ImageWidth)
      Dim iHeight As Integer = .SourceIFD.GetEntryValueIFD(TagIDsTIFF.ImageHeight)
      Dim stride As Integer = iWidth * .SourceIFD.GetEntryValueIFD(TagIDsTIFF.SamplesPerPixel)
      Dim resolution As Double = 96.0
      If .SourceIFD.ContainsKey(TagIDsTIFF.XResolution) Then resolution = .SourceIFD.GetEntryValueIFD(TagIDsTIFF.XResolution)
      Me.MainImage = GetUncompressedBitmapImage(.MainImageBuffer, iWidth, iHeight, resolution, stride)
    End If  
  End If
End Width
```

This part of code reads the TIFF metatags from the `SourceIFD`, which is a code representation of the TIFF's Image File Directory structure. The `GetUncompressedBitmapImage` function is very simple. It creates a `WritableBitmap` instance using the computed image values:

`Dim wrImage As New WriteableBitmap(iWidth, iHeigth, resolution, resolution, PixelFormats.Rgb24, Nothing)`

and try to write the pixels from the data buffer:

`wrImage.WritePixels(New Int32Rect(0, 0, iWidth, iHeigth), buffer, stride, 0)`

This is also the point, where the Exception is raised, that the value isn't in the proper range. I'm using similar logic for all other image formats without any problem. My guess is, that probably the `PixelFormats` value is wrong, but I'm not sure.

Comment: what language, what libraries? [edit] and add tags. -- did you just ask to be linked to documentation on whatever `WritableBitmap` is? [here's docs on Pixel Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pixelformats?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) -- _your data_ determines the pixel format. there isn't one single format for "uncompressed image data", it depends on the data's properties. rgb24/48 seems appropriate for 8/16-bit 3-channel data. for "samples per pixel: 1" you've got grayscale, so I'd expect `Gray16`

Comment: I use VB, but C# is also OK to me. I don't use any external library. I read the metatags and process the data directly. Handling TIFF, CR2, CR3, ARW and JPG is more or less straightforward. DNG is difficult because it is using tiled images and different type of uncompressed data. I have image width and height, bits per sample, samples per pixel, rows per strip, resolution and the binary image data (defined by StripOffsets and StripByCounts values). I compute the stride value and pass everything to the `WritableBitmap'. The exception message is also not very useful, which value is wrong?

Comment: you're gonna need to present a [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I added some lines of VB code as example to the main part